# How to prevent multiple connections in SSH?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, server

I have a Linux Server. The SSH is well-configured (my only way to access the server by the way).

Now, let's take a user, for example me (`pofilo`).

I want only **one connection** in SSH **at the same time** from the user `pofilo` (that means that nobody else can be connected with this user if someone is already connected).

Comment: It looks like the PAM module pam_limits.so can help with this. See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/400893/restricting-ssh-sessions-for-accounts-on-ubuntu-server  I've seen this module listed on other similar questions as well, so this is probably the best bet.

Comment: If you need to distinguish between SSH-logins and other logins and only limit the SSH-logins you probably are off best with SSH forced commands and your own  wrapper script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a max # of log-ins in /etc/security/limits.conf (for a user or group).

If you need an example:

```
echo "@loginrestriction  -  maxlogins 4" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
echo "username  -  maxlogins 1" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
useradd -G loginrestriction a_username
```

Comment: In case somebody needs it: [here is the documentation for `limits.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf)